# SPAN only displays some IDs

Tags: javascript, html

I like the write a little postal calculator in JS/php and not being very experienced in JS I have a (for me) strange problems that I can't understand. The SPAN element will display ALL, or the first (first few sometimes) data. But I can't select a specific ID.

Note - that code is not complete.

```
document.getElementById('au').innerHTML     = 'AU1 ec-ship $: ' + 30,
document.getElementById('ca').innerHTML     = 'CA ec-ship $: ' + ((((Math.ceil(userInput2 / 10) * 10) - 30)/10 * 1.7) +7).toFixed(2),
document.getElementById('ru').innerHTML     = 'RU ec-ship $: ' + ((((Math.ceil(userInput2 / 10) * 10) - 30)/10 * 1.7) +7).toFixed(2),
document.getElementById('uk').innerHTML     = 'UK ec-ship $: ' + ((((Math.ceil(userInput2 / 10) * 10) - 30)/10 * 1.7) +7).toFixed(2),
document.getElementById('us').innerHTML     = 'US1 ec $: '   + ((((Math.ceil(userInput2 / 10) * 10) - 30)/10 * 1.7) +7).toFixed(2),
document.getElementById('fr').innerHTML     = 'FR ec-ship $: ' + ((((Math.ceil(userInput2 / 10) * 10) - 30)/10 * 1.7) +7).toFixed(2),
document.getElementById('de').innerHTML     = 'DE ec-ship $: ' + 28

    <span id='au'></span><br>
    <span id='ca'></span><br>
    <span id='ru'></span><br>
    <span id='uk'></span><br>
    <span id='us'></span><br>   
    <span id='fr'></span><br>   
    <span id='de'></span><br>
```

What I actually want is to select one, 'us' i.e.:

```
 <span id='us'></span><br>
```

But that doesn't work at all. What is the correct way?

Comment: isn't it better if you use `<select>` instead?

Comment: Well, _userInput2_ is a number and I want to calculate without refresh the postage for different countries.

Comment: if that's the order of your code and html, then of course it wont work. the elements don't exist at the time they are being access in javascript ... look into `window.addEventListener('load'` or `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"` methods to ensure your javascript only runs once the HTML is present

Comment: so, you mean that you have an `input box` and when user type in there they will see the calculated postal for each `<span>`? if yes, just change the `,` to `;` for each `document.get ....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

http://plnkr.co/edit/Q88TrGz9ItD28WqUxo7k?p=preview

and

Snippet

OP requested `<span>` that can be displayed in any combination. So the following update involves `<input type="checkbox">` and `<labels>` and 2 lines of CSS.

---

---

http://plnkr.co/edit/0r0nBLF6W1BrSwxwpbbn?p=preview

- Put your JS in a `<script>` block
- Your code looks like PHP a lot of "," instead of ";" to terminate a statement.
- Added an input and the event listener to go with it.
- Ignore the snippet just review the Plunker.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .chk + label {
      display: none;
    }
    .chk:checked + label {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <input id="inp2" name="inp2" />
  <br/>

  <input id="aux" class="chk" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="aux"><span id='au'></span>
  </label><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;UA1</span>
  <br>
  <input id="cax" class="chk" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="cax"><span id='ca'></span>
  </label><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CA</span>
  <br>
  <input id="rux" class="chk" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="rux"><span id='ru'></span>
  </label><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;RU</span>
  <br>
  <input id="ukx" class="chk" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="ukx"><span id='uk'></span>
  </label><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;UK</span>
  <br>
  <input id="usx" class="chk" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="usx"><span id='us'></span>
  </label><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;US1</span>
  <br>
  <input id="frx" class="chk" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="frx"><span id='fr'></span>
  </label><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;FR</span>
  <br>
  <input id="dex" class="chk" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="dex"><span id='de'></span>
  </label><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;DE</span>

  <script>
    var input2 = document.getElementById('inp2');

    input2.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
      var userInput2 = parseFloat(input2.value);
      document.getElementById('au').innerHTML = 'AU1 ec-ship $: ' + 30;
      document.getElementById('ca').innerHTML = 'CA ec-ship $: ' + ((((Math.ceil(userInput2 / 10) * 10) - 30) / 10 * 1.7) + 7).toFixed(2);
      document.getElementById('ru').innerHTML = 'RU ec-ship $: ' + ((((Math.ceil(userInput2 / 10) * 10) - 30) / 10 * 1.7) + 7).toFixed(2);
      document.getElementById('uk').innerHTML = 'UK ec-ship $: ' + ((((Math.ceil(userInput2 / 10) * 10) - 30) / 10 * 1.7) + 7).toFixed(2);
      document.getElementById('us').innerHTML = 'US1 ec $: ' + ((((Math.ceil(userInput2 / 10) * 10) - 30) / 10 * 1.7) + 7).toFixed(2);
      document.getElementById('fr').innerHTML = 'FR ec-ship $: ' + ((((Math.ceil(userInput2 / 10) * 10) - 30) / 10 * 1.7) + 7).toFixed(2);
      document.getElementById('de').innerHTML = 'DE ec-ship $: ' + 28;
    }, false);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But in case I want just to display `<span id='us'></span><br>` then it isn't working.

Comment: You mean only the US?

Comment: Yes. I have one page that does all the calculations. But on the actual php working page I want to put a condition, something like `if($country == 'us') {echo '<span id='us'></span>';}`

Comment: Made it into a select input, take a look

Comment: SELECT is not really what I want, I like to display just one result. I guess I can do `<span id='fr' style=display:none></span>` on all that I **don't** want. Doesn't very elegant but would do the job.

Comment: So you really want spans? Ok.. one min.